# How to encrypt URL GET request in the address bar?

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 4.0 in my web application. Here I am using an anchor tag to call the controller.

```
<a href="testDetails?id=3">Details</a>  //i.e a GET request
```

Now I don't want to show this `id=3` in my address bar, which is possible by using a POST request.

Is there another way to do this, if it is possible by using some encryption format then can you provide me any example?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is possible to use some sort of encryption method on that ID and then to assign it dynamically to your href, however, would it not be easier just to use a form instead of an href to accomplish what you want here? like so:

```
<form method="post" action="testDetails">
    <input type="text" hidden name="id" value="3"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

This way you can access the POST var "id" to get your value and it will not show up in the address bar like you requested.